# How do I center this element on the page? I can only center the text within colored background

Tags: html, css, element, center

It creates exactly what I need but I cannot center to whole element on the page. centering will only center the text within the background colored area. What am I doing wrong?

I tried many different code combination but cannot make this work.

> GROW YOUR BUSINESS WITH US

```
<h1 style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; background-color: #273b86; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 640px;">GROW YOUR BUSINESS WITH US</h1>
```

I would like whole element above to be centered on the page.

Comment: Display block, `margin: auto`, there are lots of questions on this, please do a search on google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1):

You also could just change the display attr to block and add margin:auto to it!
I placed it into a div with 1000px width for you to view, but you just need the h1

```html
<div style="width:1000px;">

<h1 style="display: block; text-align: center; background-color: #273b86; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 640px; margin:auto;">GROW YOUR BUSINESS WITH US</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add div around H1 and add width and margin:auto like

```
<div style="width:650px; margin: auto;"><h1 style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; background-color: #273b86; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 640px; ">GROW YOUR BUSINESS WITH US</h1><div>
```

Or like Huangism do

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; background-color: #273b86; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 640px; margin: auto;">GROW YOUR BUSINESS WITH US</h1>
```

Comment: The display block does not need to be on there, I only comment on it because the OP has inline-block. Wrapping the element is totally unnecessary

Comment: Like Huangism said, I removed display:block and also works. Thanks Huangism

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90vw;

}

.container > div{
    width: 150px; /* very impotent */
    margin:auto;/* center position */
    border:1px #CCC solid;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div> center div </div>
</div>
```